# How to optimize listview.builder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using List View builder in my app with each element having a future builder because i am getting duration for each song on the list. I cannot take all the durations at once because it is taking too much time. The list view is very slow and the scrolling is not smooth. How can i optimize the List view builder ?

Comment: Can you post the code, please? Edit your post and insert some snippet to describe your problem

Answer (score 0):

you need to use compute if the process is too heavy, [example](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing):

```
Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response = await client
      .get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos'));

  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
  return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}

// A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>.
List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```